# Compile Error when trying to return PChar or OleVariant for UDF

Tags: excel, delphi-7

The title doesn't quite capture the essence of the issue.

I have a UDF function that returns a PChar.

```
function AccountDescription(sAccountId: PChar) : PChar; stdcall;
```

This was working fine but I realized I wanted to return #N/A if the accountId was not found.

I discovered CVErr(xlErrNA) and changed the Signature to return OleVariant.
But now I am receiving [Error] Incompatible types: 'OleVariant' and 'PAnsiChar'.

I could not find any information on how to resolve this so I figure my understanding of the problem must not be correct.

I tried just passing a string which compiled but produced a runtime error of "Invalid variant type".

The full code is:

```
function AccountDescription(sAccountId: PChar): OleVariant; stdcall;
var
  strResult: string;
  strPChar : PChar;
begin

    try
        strResult:= repo.GetAccount(sAccountId).Description;
        strPChar := strAlloc(length(strResult)+1) ;
        StrPCopy(strPChar, strResult) ;
        Result := strPChar;
    except
      Result := CVErr(xlErrNA);
    end;

end;
```

Note: Is excel responsible for destroying the string or is that my cleanup?  Should I be creating a copy or should I just be returning a pointer to an existing string.  After typing it I feel like I should be returning a pointer.

**Update:** 
Removed some irrelevant code in the example.

Now using:

```
function AccountDescription(sAccountId: PChar): OleVariant; stdcall;
var
  strResult: string;
begin

    try
        Result := PChar(repo.GetAccount(sAccountId).Description);            
    except
      Result := CVErr(xlErrNA);
    end;

end;
```

Comment: So my current add-in already has a memory leak.  When I switched between creating a PChar Copy and
    Result := PChar(repo.GetAccount(sAccountId).Description);
I have the same amount of memory leakage.  So I got problems elsewhere when it comes to memory leaking.

Comment: I tracked down the memory leak and fixed that one and re-tested.  I can now see that I am leaking memory by doing a copy.  When I switch to PChar(....Description) then I stop leaking memory.  The description comes from a repo that is in memory.

Comment: Still cannot figure out how to return either a string or an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `PChar` cast, you can assign a `String` directly to an `OleVariant` (it will be converted by the RTL into a `BSTR` that the receiver will then free when done using it):

```
Result := repo.GetAccount(sAccountId).Description;
```

As for reporting an error, do you have a viable `CVErr()` function in your Delphi code? In VB, `CVErr()` returns a `Variant` of type `Error` (`varError` in Delphi) containing an error code (`xlErrNA` is 2042). Delphi has a [`VarAsError()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarAsError) function for that same purpose:

```
Result := VarAsError(2042);
```

Comment: So I had bad test data.  I thought I was successfully returning a string but I had a nil object which throw an exception and attempted to return the CVErr(xlErrNa).  This is the failure point.  It is from a 3rd party tool add-in-express.  But I also tried VarAsError(xlErrNa) but that failed.  Debugger confirmed that xlErrNa is 2042 from Excel2000.pas.
I think the problem is I use the Excel Register function and I cannot specify a variant as a return type. Register("AccountDescription","CC").

Comment: From the add-in-express documentation it uses the TypeLibrary to specify a UDF but the add-in is trying to only register the UDF's if the workbooks open matches our criteria otherwise in that session the UDF's do not get register.  So we are using the  ExecuteExcel4Macro command to load the UDF's on demand but I think that method might be limited.